# How is it possible to get tracked features from tango APIs used for motion tracking

Tags: google-project-tango

As it is shown in [Project Tango GTC Video](https://youtu.be/1HhOmF22oYA?t=1m18s), some local features are extracted and tracked for motion estimation that is then fused with accelerometer data.

Since any developer may need to track features to develop his/her apps, I was wondering if there would be a way to get those features through `APIs`.
Although it is possible to extract some point and retrieve their flow using estimated `6DOF` pose returned by the `APIs`, it adds extra overhead. Another issue with this approach is that the pure visual flow (including outliers) is not achievable and is influenced by `IMU` data.

So my question is that if these features are tracked using hardware-accelerated algorithms, how can we get them using `APIs` without having to implement it and do a redundant task.

Any answer and suggestion would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It is straightforward to compile OpenCV for the Tango with nVidia's TADP package. Use 3.0r4. You may need to merge some OpenCV-4-Android bits but it's easy, and the ES examples will fail on the device but don't sweat it.

Comment: So You think the built-in algorithm for optical flow uses OpenCV? And if I cross compile OpenCV using nVidia's package, I can get Tegra accelerated version of that algorithm, right? If this is true, I still need to run another task to get tracked features while the built-in motion tracking does a similar thing in the background. Redundant tasks, hmm?

Answer (score 0):

Google released the "Project Tango ADF Inspector" on play store -  I haven't actually had any time to play with it, but its the first thing to offer any look inside that data - I think Google considers this data sensitive and is cautious in this area, with good reason - If you look for the starred "important" note on [this page](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/overview/area-learning) you should get a feel for the sensitivity of that issue.

Comment: You're right. But ADF inspector is an app to explore collected pointcloud. I am looking for the intermediate data that is used to track motion. The "important" note does make sense as it is quiet memory demanding to store all those information.

Comment: Sorry - wasn't clear enough - the starred comment at the bottom of the page concerning privacy