# Getting detected features from Google Tango Motion Tracking API

Tags: google-project-tango, slam-algorithm

I would like to know how to get the current feature points used in motion tracking and the ones that are present in the learned area (detected or not).

There is an older, related post without an useful answer: 
[How is it possible to get tracked features from tango APIs used for motion tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30601755/how-is-it-possible-to-get-tracked-features-from-tango-apis-used-for-motion-track). I'm using the tango to not do SLAM and IMU-integration on my own.

What do I need to do, to visualize the tracked features like they did in some of the presentation videos. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2y7NX-HUlMc (0:35 - 0:55)

What I want in general is some kind of measure or visual guidance on how good the devices learned the current environment. I know, there is is the Inspector App but I need this information on the fly.

Thanks for your Help ;)

Comment: Currently, there's not way to get "features" from API.  Just out of curiosity, if there;s an app show feature tracks, would that be helpful? Because even we expose API for feature points, I'm not sure how valuable they are besides of inspecting if certain area is good for tracking or not..

Comment: its not about checking if the areas are good for tracking. its about which areas are present in your learned area model and which are not. I think the feature points (mapped into 3D) are the first and simplest possibility to get there..

Comment: I see you point, you would like to know what the ADF is representing.. However, the feature point wouldn't really help with that, even we extract the points, it will be relatively sparse, and it hardly represent a space visually..

Comment: You're right! More advanced information, whatever they might look like, would also be great ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check if an area is present in your learned area model and which is not, you can use the Tango Debug Overlay App. It has a field 'Tracking Success' that only counts up if the device sees learned feature points (ADF on) or finds new feature points (ADF off) (http://grauonline.de/alexwww/tmp/tango_debug_overlay_app.jpg). Additionally, you can request that debug information like Tango Debug Overlay App does (as a simple text) via UDP port 29361 in your App and parse the returned debug text (although this is not recommended at all for a real app as this interface is not documented)
PS: In Tango Core 01-19-2017 this counter does not seem to work anymore.